# Yammer API Find Pending Users

Tags: yammer

Is it possible to find a list of Yammer users in the 'pending' state using the API?
(we have a growing list of old invites that need to be purged regularly)

Tried a number of options:

The find all users endpoint, paging to 50 per page seems to only return 'active' users (scanned 100+ pages). 
https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users.json

The find by email endpoint returns all user states, although requires knowing the email.

The export users API endpoint produces a .zip file

Pending users were recently added as mentionable:
https://about.yammer.com/yammer-blog/mentioning-pending-users-designing-building-testing-features-yammer Should this recent change have also made pending users visible via the users.json endpoint ?

I know pending users can be identified in the manual user.csv extract by having no join date, no deletion and no suspended date, although how can they be identified via the API? users.json seems to not provide this functionality.

Has anyone been able to automate the deletion of pending users in Yammer via the API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Data Export API. Extract the users.csv from the ZIP file using code and then filter for pending users. Pending users do not have a joined_at, suspended_at, or deleted_at date.

NOTE: If you are intended to "remove" a pending user, you must **always check** if that email address also has an active user associated. An email address can show up multiple times in users.csv. When you do remove a user always suspend the user because it can be undone.

Answer (score -1):

Here's an endpoint you can run a GET on an return the JSON output of the pending user list:

```
https://www.yammer.com/<your Yammer network>/contacts/network
```

Example:

```
https://www.yammer.com/contoso.com/contacts/network
```

Note: this is an undocumented endpoint so the functionality could change at any time.

Comment: Thanks, although the response from that endpoint is a HTML script which links to a local Yammer cookie. I can't see any way to use it for retrieval of pending users.